# obj-c delegate method is null

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, storyboard

My `FetchVenuesView` preceeds the `VenuesIDController`. `VenuesIDController` is the second tabbar item in a `tabbarcontroller`.  `FetchVenuesView` is not part of the tabbar.

The first item in the tabbar is a `tableview` in which i can call a delegate without issue.
However when I try and call the delegate in `VenuesIDController` it always shows up in the log as null.

What do I do here? Do i connect the delegate in the storyboard? How?

I have a `FetchVenuesViewController.h`

```
#import "VenueTableViewController.h" 
#import "VenueIDController.h"

@interface FetchVenuesViewController : UIViewController< VenueTableViewControllerDelegate, VenueIDControllerDelegate>{
    NSDictionary* venueJSON;
    NSDictionary* idJSON;

};

@property (strong) NSDictionary* idJSON;


- (void)VenueFetch;

- (void)IDFetch;


@end
```

In `FetchVenuesViewController.m`

```
@synthesize idJSON;

- (void)IDFetch {

    //request some webservice 


    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
    //save the response



    if (data) {

        id IDJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (!IDJSON) {
           //handle error

        }
        else {


        //do something

        }



    } else {
        // fetch failed

    }

    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
}

-(NSDictionary *)getID{
    [self IDfetch];
    NSLog(@"json%@",idJSON);
    return idJSON;
}
```

In `VenueIDController.h`

```
@protocol VenueIDControllerDelegate;

@interface VenueIDController : UIViewController{

}


@property (assign) id <VenueIDControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(IBAction)getIDData:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol VenueIDControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(NSDictionary *)getID;
@end
```

and in `VenueIDController.m`

```
@interface VenueIDController (){
        NSMutableArray* IDData;
        UIImage* IDBarcode;
    }
    -(void) displayIDData:(NSDictionary*)data;
    @end

    @implementation VenueIDController
    @synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        VenueIDController *vid = [[VenueIDController alloc] init]; 
        vid.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%@",vid);


    }
    return self;
}


    -(void) displayIDData:(NSDictionary*)data{

        [delegate getID];


        NSDictionary* idJSON = data;


    }
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to *set* the `VenueIDController`'s delegate?

Comment: Try setting the delegate programmatically.

Comment: i tried `VenueIDController *id = [[VenueIDController alloc] init]; id.delegate = self;` in `initWithNibName` ... Still nothing. Do i set it somewhere else?

Comment: if you're setting it there it should appear @H2CO3 do you agree? does it still not work?

Comment: @Eva611 and ellienphilly it should really work then.

Comment: @H2CO3 look at where I'm setting it... it doesn't fire all all. should i set it somehwere else? im trying to fetch the `idJSON` in the idcontroller... it's a second tab bar item does that make any difference?

Comment: @ellieinphilly I'm wondering how this compiles at all. `id` is a reserved Objective-C typename, I doubt it be allowed to be used as a variable name...

Comment: @H2CO3 oops you're right... had set it as `vid` typo in the code above... `vid`

Comment: Whereabouts *exactly* is your `vid.delegate = self`? Is it in your `FetchVenuesViewController`'s `initWithNibName:`? If so, what are you doing with the `VenueIDController` you are creating there? You're creating a new one. Are you ever keeping that? That object is the one you're the delegate of.

Comment: @H2CO3 you can call a variable `id` if you want. Although I certainly would never recommend it for similar reasons to using any reserved word (even overlooked C++ ones like `class`, `friend`, etc).

Comment: @mattjgalloway I don't see why it is permitted at all... It's just brainless to enable using them like this.

Comment: @H2CO3 I wouldn't say brainless, but I would say it's a potential for debugging headaches. Mainly because of readability including Xcode syntax highlighting kicking in to highlight the keyword in pink.

Comment: @mattjgalloway Well, you're too permissive :) It certainly is, and I'd count it as a serious design and/or codign style mistake.

Comment: @mattjgalloway `vid.delegate = self` is in `venueIDController`'s `initWithNibName`

Comment: @ellieinphilly well that makes no sense. Can you show the `initWithNibName` method for `VenueIDController` then please?

Comment: If your view controller comes from an interface builder file then the 'init...' method is not called. You can use 'awakeFromNib'

Comment: @mattjgalloway shown above in edit. thanks

Comment: @ellieinphilly 2 things - 1) You're creating a new `VenueIDController` within that init method. It'll "go away" at the end of that method (assuming you're using ARC). 2) As Chris Lundie says, if you're using a NIB/Storyboard then `initWithNibName:` will not be called.

Comment: @mattjgalloway tried http://pastebin.com/mkwTkE2i doesn't seem to work either. i think i didn't get the fundamentals right here... could you show me how i could fix this

Comment: You shouldn't be setting `self` as `delegate` of `self`. That's really not what you want. You want your `FetchVenuesViewController` to be the delegate of your `VenueIDController`, I assume. You need to set it wherever you create your `VenueIDController` and `FetchVenuesViewController` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init` on `VenueIDController` appears wrong. you're already in an init, so you don't need to create another one. instead you should have `self.delegate = self`. The `vid` object you are creating there isn't going to be retained.

Comment: Yes but it's not that he wants `self` to be `delegate` of `self`. It's the `FetchVenuesViewController` that wants to be the delegate.